# Understanding there is no "MedianIFs" function, is there a formula work around?

Tags: excel, formula

Essentially, I need a formula like "averageifs" to find median

I need the median of `H:H if A:A="Example", if C:C = B1`

This is my Averageifs for context.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Promo!$H$2:$H$1269,Promo!$A$2:$A$1269,PSheet!$B10,Promo!$C$2:$C$1269,PSheet!$B$1)
```

Any help will be truly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Promo!$A$2:$A$1269=PSheet!$B10)*(Promo!$C$2:$C$1269=PSheet!$B$1),Promo!$H$2:$H$1269))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Scott Craner, I owe you a beer or whatever it is you enjoy! Thank you!!!

Comment: @user11239160 just please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.