# Median for data between 2 dates

Tags: excel-formula, median

In one column I have date/time format ranging from July - Dec 2022. In another column I have the corresponding time values for task completion. Example of the data is as below -

Sample Data:
[image: Sample data]

I want to calculate the median for the date range of

Median Date Range:
[image: Median date range]

How can I calculate the median hours for particular date range?

I am expecting the data as below:
[image]

Comment: Just to double check: Is it `median` or `average` you are looking for? I ask because `=AverageIfs()` function would solve this without having to resort to Array/CSE formulas or some other trickery.

Comment: Ya .. I got the average data , but for Median I dont see any MedianIf kind of function ..

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303103/2221001 It's very similar requirements where you want a `median` and you have two conditions (in your case, greater than your start date and less than your end date).

Comment: If you paste your data as text in the question it is much easier to help you. [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)